# Access a variable from one keyword to another Robot framework

Tags: python, excel, robotframework

I have created a variable (${sResultFile}) in one Keyword (1) as follows:
[image: This is keyword file 1]

```
create excel file
    ${sResultFile}    Add TimeStamp to File    ${sResultFilePath}
    Create File    ${sResultFile}
    Append to file    ${sResultFile}    TC_Name\tStatus\tComments\n
    Set Global Variable    ${sResultFile}    ${sResultFile}
    [Return]    ${sResultFile}
```

Now I want to access this ${sResultFile} in another keyword (2) which is in the same resource file

[image: This is keyword file 2]

[image]

As you see I am not able to access ${sResultFile} in keyword file 2. I tried making it Global, but no luck. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

your question is not clear.

----> If you want to use result of first keyword `${sResultFile}` into second keyword then replace second line of your second keyword with

```
append to file      create excel file     ${cTCNo}\....
```

----> If you want to use result of first three lines of first keyword then create an another keyword and return the result which can be used where ever you want

```
Some Keyword
      ${sResultFile}    Add TimeStamp to File    ${sResultFilePath}
      Create File    ${sResultFile}
      [return]  Append to file    ${sResultFile}    TC_Name\tStatus\tComments\n
```

So that second line of second keyword would be

```
append to file      Some Keyword     ${cTCNo}\....
```

Please let me know if you have any issue

Comment: First keyword is to crate a excel file with 3 columns TC_Name, Status and Comments. This keyword I am calling in Suite Setup, so that when I try to run a suite the excel is generated. The second keyword is called from the testcase inside that suite. So second keyword will append the test case name into the column "TC_Name". The second image is wrong. I have updated it. So please check

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably following:

```
Set Test Variable    ${sResultFile}    ${sResultFile}
```